# mongodb - triger a query once a record changes

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to define some kind of a update query trigger on a specific field?

For example, lets say i have a collection that contain people, and might have family relations. e.g : father to son. which means one record can point to another. (some sort of a tree).

Every time i update a specific field, i would like to also update the records parents in the tree (if i update a son's field, i would like to trigger an update and update the father as well).

Is anything like that possible? (being done entirely on DB level)

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely on a DB, but there are https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/ and a convenience wrapper for Atlas users https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/triggers/.

The trigger is originated on the DB, and the logic to perform the query is on the listener side - the application, component, or a separate service.